# Why my relation does not want to work?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have two entities `Skill` and its type `SkillType`. The relationship looks as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="skills")
 */
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var SkillType
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SkillType", inversedBy="skills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $type;

    //Getters and Setters
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="skill_types")
 */
class SkillType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Skill[]|ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="type")
     */
    protected $skills;

    /**
     * SkillType constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->skills = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I have also a form creating the relationship beetwen this two

```
class SkillType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
                'multiple' => false,
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SkillType',
                'choice_label' => 'id',
                'by_reference' => false
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Skill',
        ]);
    }
}
```

How i have tried to fix the error?

1. Adding `, cascade={"persist"}` to mapping on either side also on both sides
2. Adding `$entityManager->merge($entity);` before `createForm(SkillType::class, $entity`

My request content looks as follow: `{"skill":{"type":1},"id":"1"}`. So as you can see it should create a relation between `Skill` with `id=1` and `SkillType` with `id=1`.

The error i get when i submit form is:

**Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?**

Stack Trace:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\RuntimeException: Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
at n/a
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php line 119

at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\IdReader->getIdValue(object(SkillType))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/DoctrineChoiceLoader.php line 122

at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\DoctrineChoiceLoader->loadValuesForChoices(array(object(SkillType)), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/LazyChoiceList.php line 134

at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList->getValuesForChoices(array(object(SkillType)))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php line 37

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer->transform(object(SkillType))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 1092

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->normToView(object(SkillType))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 352

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(SkillType))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 57

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(Skill), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 385

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(Skill))
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 477

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->initialize()
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 226

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
    in /var/www/public_html/api-hb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this could be error in db schema. First check your db structure, if i'm right problem could occur there. My concept is to delete this relation, run doctrine schema update and create this relation again.

I think reason that you get this error only in one Entity is not properly reflected in DB due some previous changes that doctrine could not handle properly on schema update.